# Hyperlink not responding

Tags: html, slideshow

My landing page has a slideshow with text and links that direct the visitor to it's corresponding page.

Landing page link: http://karenrubkiewicz.com/martin/

The yellow arrow in the second box should be a clickable link, but it doesn't respond.

Here is my coding:

HTML

```
<div id="maximage">

<div>
   <img src="images/00_landing page/backgrounds/background_01.jpg" alt="" width="1400" height="1050" />
   <div class="in-slide-content">
   PLACES
   </div>
   <a class="in-slide-content2" href="places.html"><img src="images/arrow.png" height="20px"></a>
</div>

<div>
   <img src="images/00_landing page/backgrounds/background_02.jpg" alt="" width="1400" height="1050" />
   <div class="in-slide-content">
   PLACES
   </div>
   <a class="in-slide-content2" href="places.html"><img src="images/arrow.png" height="20px"></a>
</div>

ETC...

</div> <!--END MAXIMAGE DIV-->
```

CSS

```
#maximage {
/* position:fixed !important;*/
display:block;
}

.in-slide-content {
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
font-size:16pt;
letter-spacing:1px;
position: absolute;
right:63px;
bottom:240px;
width: 220px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
color:#FFF;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
padding-top:23px;
padding-bottom:23px;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
}

.in-slide-content2{
position: absolute;
right:63px;
bottom:162px;
width: 220px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
text-align:center;
padding-top:25px;
padding-bottom:25px;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
}

.in-slide-content2 a{
position: relative;
display:block;
}
```

I am using a maximage plugin, I am not sure whether that could be a possible cause of inference.

One more note, in my HTML, when I remove a certain div, the link begins to work, only then my slideshow falls apart.

EXAMPLE

```
<div id="maximage">

<div> <----REMOVE THIS DIV
<img src="images/00_landing page/backgrounds/background_01.jpg" alt="" width="1400" height="1050" />
 <div class="in-slide-content">
PLACES
</div>
<a class="in-slide-content2" href="places.html"><img src="images/arrow.png" height="20px"></a>
</div> <-----AND REMOVE THIS DIV


 ETC...

</div> <!--END MAXIMAGE DIV-->
```

I'm really stuck on this one.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your slideshow and link are overlapping each other creating some confusion

Comment: `body .mc-cycle { z-index:-1; }` from the `jquery.maximage.css` stylesheet is responsible – it places the whole element behind your `.wrapper` element in the stack. Since this seems to be a stylesheet that comes with the plugin, see whether you have implemented something wrong; or overwrite that `z-index` with a rule with higher specificity.

Comment: maybe try adding the img via css `.in-slide-content2 {
    background-image: url("yourimagefile");}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in CSS:

```
#nav {
z-index: 2;
}
body .mc-cycle {
z-index: 0;
}
```

If it wont help, then this:

```
#nav {
z-index: 2 !important;
}
body .mc-cycle {
z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your codes on your site, (which btw look different from what you posted here), I think things get complicated when your `in-slide-content` and `in-slide-content2` `div`s are enclosed in your `mc-image` with its background set to your image file (instead of using an `img` tag).

This is what your current codes look like:

```
<div class="mc-image " ... background-image: url(http://karenrubkiewicz.com/martin/images/00_landing%20page/backgrounds/background_01.jpg);" data-href="">
    <div class="in-slide-content">PLACES</div>
    <a class="in-slide-content2" href="places.html"><img src="images/arrow.png" height="20px"></a>
</div>
```

Try convert your `mc-image` to an image tag and extract your `in-slide-content` and `in-slide-content2` out of your `maximage`.

I think this live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akv292/7z32m/) on jsfiddle is very similar to what you are trying to do.

The reason why manipulating the `z-index` attribute (of the image, the anchor tag etc.) in your `css` script probably won't work is because the `jquery.cycle.all.js` script assigns all your images with some high value `z-index` on start-up so that they can stack on top of each other.

```
// line 295 - 303
// set position and zIndex on all the slides
$slides.css({position: 'absolute', top:0, left:0}).hide().each(function(i) {
    var z;
    if (opts.backwards)
        z = first ? i <= first ? els.length + (i-first) : first-i : els.length-i;
    else
        z = first ? i >= first ? els.length - (i-first) : first-i : els.length-i;
    $(this).css('z-index', z)
});
```

As the script cycles through your images, some codes (I haven't figured out where yet) will reset the `z-index` of that image to `z+1`, so that current image will be stack on top of the rest. I tried setting the `z-index` of some of your HTML elements to some ridiculous high number but to no avail. Anyway, I still think the cleanest way to solve this is to look at the fiddle I shared.